# Trying to create a Dice game

Tags: python-3.x

I need to trow a number of dice (based on user input) - two, three, four dice several times (again based on user input). Then I have to add result of each round so that in the end I have a winner. I can print out random numbers by the following code, but have no idea how to add them after several iterations. Please advise!

```
import random

list1 = []
count = 0
number_of_dice = int(input("\nHow many dice would ou like to use? "))
for x in range(number_of_dice):
    print(random.randint(1,6))
```

Comment: Add them to the list?

Comment: `list1.append(sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(number_of_dice)))`